# How to get a hold of the ActionBar menu at UI setup time?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

For some reason, `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called AFTER `onResume()` in my app... Therefore, I  just can't get a hold of the menu while I'm setting up my UI (between `onCreate()` and `onResume()`), which results in not being able to setup the corresponding action items for my ActionBar...

The only work-around I've found so far is to manually call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` right before `onCreate()` returns; that way `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is immediately called, I get a hold of the menu and then I can finally add the desired action items.

Has anyone experienced this issue? How are you supposed to programmatically setup your action items given `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called after `onResume()`?

My app is running on JellyBean, it uses the built-in ActionBar (no ActionBarSherlock), `android:minSdkVersion="14"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="16"`

Comment: Quick sanity check, you're talking about the *activity* onCreate & onResume, right? as opposed to the corresponding methods in Fragment

Comment: Why can't you setup the menu items in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` (instead of using it simply to store a reference to the menu for later use)?

Comment: I'm with user113215 here, why do you need to know about the menu in `onResume()`? It doesn't seem right.

Comment: @AlexanderLucas: Yes I'm talking about the Activity's onCreate and onResume methods.

Comment: @AlexanderLucas and user113215: I need to add/remove action items on the fly given some user generated events; these events of course can happen way after onCreateOptionsMenu() was executed... That's why I need to get a hold of the Menu

Comment: What user* said. Call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` when the user performs something that needs to update the menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First consider that perhaps you shouldn't be doing this. It sounds like your idea might go against typical design patterns for Android. If your menu is changing in response to a user selection, for example, you should use contextual action mode instead.

- From the [Action Bar API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ChoosingActionItems):

  > As a general rule, all items in the options menu (let alone action items) should have a global impact on the app, rather than affect only a small portion of the interface. [...] So, even before deciding whether a menu item should appear as an action item, be sure that the item has a global scope for the current activity.
- From the [Menu API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu):

  > You should never change items in the options menu based on the `View` currently in focus. When in touch mode (when the user is not using a trackball or d-pad), views cannot take focus, so you should never use focus as the basis for modifying items in the options menu. If you want to provide menu items that are context-sensitive to a `View`, use a [Context Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu).

---

Barring that, if you do want to change the menu items as you have described, you should **make the change in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`**. When the event occurs that requires changing the menu items, put the relevant information into a field and call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. Override `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` and check the value of the field to determine which menu items to add/remove.

(It would also work to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to modify which menu items should be shown, although this approach is not recommended.)

More from the [Menu API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu):

> You should use `onCreateOptionsMenu()` only to create the initial
>   menu state and not to make changes during the activity lifecycle.
>   If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur
>   during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the
>   `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method.
>
> This method passes you the `Menu` object as it currently exists so you
>   can modify it, such as add, remove, or disable items. (Fragments also
>   provide an `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` callback.)
>
> - On Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`
>     each time the user opens the options menu (presses the Menu button).
> - On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be
>     open when menu items are presented in the action bar. When an event
>     occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call
>     `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to request that the system call
>     `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.